# $K(G,n) \otimes K(G',n) \to K(G \times G',n)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, eilenberg-maclane-spaces

Let $G,G'$ be two abelian groups and $X$ a topological space, we know that there is a natural bijection
$$H^n(X,G) \cong [X, K(G,n)]$$
where $K(G,n)$ is an Eilenberg-Maclane space. Therefore, from the product
$$H^n(X,G) \times H^n(X,G') \to H^n(X,G \times G').$$
We get a natural map $\boxtimes: [X, K(G,n) \times K(G',n)] = [X, K(G,n)] \times [X,K(G',n)] \to [X, K(G\times G',n)]$. Taking $X = K(G,n) \times K(G',n)$ then
$$\boxtimes(id_X): K(G,n) \times K(G',n) \to K(G \times G',n).$$
I am struggling at proving this map induces an isomorphism on homology groups, any suggestion is appreciated. This comes from a paper of Seminar Cartan on *DGA-algebras and DGA-modules*, which is available [here](http://www.numdam.org/article/SHC_1954-1955__7_1_A2_0.pdf).

Comment: $K(G,n) \times K(G′,n)$  is itself a $K(G \times G′,n)$, so that $H^n(X, G) \times H^n(X, G')  \cong   [X,K(G,n)] \times [X, K(G′,n)]  \cong  [X,K(G,n) \times K(G′,n)] \cong H^n(X, G \times G').$

Comment: Then you only need to check that this isomorphism coincides with the map you are interested in. Which should be ok, I guess.

Comment: Maybe relevant https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3237596/when-do-elements-of-operatornamehomg-g-correspond-to-invertible-self-maps

Comment: @Darne, I completely forgot the fact $K(G,n) \times K(G',n) = K(G \times G',n)$, but I still wonder if I could find the inverse of $\boxtimes(id_X)$, maybe $\boxtimes(id_{K(G\times G',n)}$.

Comment: The projection homomorphisms $G\xleftarrow{pr_1} G\times G\xrightarrow{pr_2} G$ induce homotopy classes of maps $K(G,n)\xleftarrow{q_1}K(G\times G,n)\xrightarrow{q_2} K(G,n)$. Then $(q_1,q_2):K(G\times G,n)\rightarrow K(G,n)\times K(G,n)$ is the inverse of $\boxtimes(id)$.